# Thunar hiding and displaying side panel on mouseclick and moving mouse around

Tags: xubuntu, 16.10, interface, thunar

I am having the following problem with the file manager thunar (1.6.10 in xubuntu 16.10):

Whenever I click with my mouse or just move it around in an open thunar window it keeps hiding and displaying the side panel. That makes moving around folders pretty annoying. Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Suddenly started happening today. I haven't installed any updates or anything else since the last time I had my PC turned on.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and don't know why it "hide" itself (seems related to opening a folder with a lot of metadata on files...), but it is not gone!
In fact, there is no option to hide it, it just resized, so click on the left border, drag on the inside, and it pop up again :)